# Vector Align amsmath isn't working as intended. Is there another way than using the and '&' sign?

Tags: equations, align, vector

I am only trying to have each element aligned with the associated symbol from Eq. 1.
Sorry if the question is too obvious. I tried looking at other examples, but non had the exact same issue as me.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\maketitle


\begin{align}
    &\underline{s}_{t+1} &= s_t + &T_s \cdot \dot{\underline{s}_t} \\

  \begin{pmatrix}
    &\theta_{t+1} \\ 
    \dot{\theta}_{t+1} \\ 
    x_{t+1} \\ 
    \dot{x}_{t+1}
  \end{pmatrix}%_{4\times1}
    \mkern5mu &= \mkern5mu 
  \begin{pmatrix}
    \theta_t \\ 
    \dot{\theta}_t \\ 
    x_t \\ 
    \dot{x}_t   
    \end{pmatrix}
    \mkern5mu + \mkern5mu &T_s \mkern5mu \cdot
  \begin{pmatrix}
    \dot{\theta}_t \\ 
    \ddot{\theta}_t \\ 
    \dot{x}_t \\ 
    \ddot{x}_t  
  \end{pmatrix}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Here is what I am getting from this code. Thanks in advanced!
[image]

Edit: I forgot to mention, that I would like both the equations to have a number assigned to them. The array wrapped in the environment equation wouldn't do the trick apparently.

Comment: I think the & in your matrix might be breaking things — have you tried moving it outside?

Comment: @confusedandbemused Yes, I tried. It looked a bit different, but still not right

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a situation where `align` isn't best suited. You could use `alignat` but as long as you need only one equation number I'd go with a simple `array`.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article} % twocolumn for smaller snapshot

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{array}[t]{ % or [b] to align the number with the bottom equation
                 c
                 @{{}={}}
                 c
                 @{{} + \; T_s \; \cdot{}} % change the two \; to spacings you like
                 c
                }
\underline{s}_{t+1} & s_t & \underline{\dot{s}}_t \\[2ex]
\begin{pmatrix}
  \theta_{t+1} \\ 
  \dot{\theta}_{t+1} \\ 
  x_{t+1} \\ 
  \dot{x}_{t+1}
\end{pmatrix}%_{4\times1}
&
\begin{pmatrix}
  \theta_t \\ 
  \dot{\theta}_t \\ 
  x_t \\ 
  \dot{x}_t   
\end{pmatrix}
&
\begin{pmatrix}
  \dot{\theta}_t \\ 
  \ddot{\theta}_t \\ 
  \dot{x}_t \\ 
  \ddot{x}_t  
\end{pmatrix}
\end{array}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can change the space between `+`, `T_s`, and `\cdot` if you like. Note also that I've used

```
\underline{\dot{s}}_t
```

instead of your

```
\dot{\underline{s}_t}
```

The latter would centre the dot over the whole subformula with the subscript instead of the `s` alone.

---

**EDIT**: If both equations should be numbered then one should put everything in boxes and have TeX measure their width. This could be made more automatic by using the package `eqparbox` but I'm not familiar with it.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article} % twocolumn for smaller snapshot

\usepackage{mathtools}% loads amsmath

\begin{document}

% measure larger vector
\sbox0{$\begin{pmatrix}
  \theta_{t+1} \\ 
  \dot{\theta}_{t+1} \\ 
  x_{t+1} \\ 
  \dot{x}_{t+1}
\end{pmatrix}$}%
% measure thinner vector
\sbox1{$\begin{pmatrix}
  \dot{\theta}_t \\ 
  \ddot{\theta}_t \\ 
  \dot{x}_t \\ 
  \ddot{x}_t  
\end{pmatrix}$}
\begin{gather}
\mathmakebox[\wd0]{\underline{s}_{t+1}} = \mathmakebox[\wd1]{s_t} + \; T_s \; \cdot  \mathmakebox[\wd1]{\underline{\dot{s}}_t} \\[2ex]
\copy0
=
\mathmakebox[\wd1]{
\begin{pmatrix}
  \theta_t \\ 
  \dot{\theta}_t \\ 
  x_t \\ 
  \dot{x}_t   
\end{pmatrix}}
+ \; T_s \; \cdot \copy1
\end{gather}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hey @campa Thanks for the replay! With array I don't have a number assigned to the equation now and I can't use this in my document unfortunately

Comment: @johnny_1010 I've added a workaround but it's not pretty...

Comment: A true legend. Thanks man :)

Answer (score 5):

You can use eqparbox. The label to use should be unique to the group of boxes to typeset with the same width.

[image]

The code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{eqparbox}

\newcommand{\eqmath}[3][c]{%
  % #1 = alignment, default c, #2 = label, #2 = math material
  \eqmakebox[#2][#1]{$\displaystyle#3$}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\eqmath{1A}{\underline{s}_{t+1}} &= 
\eqmath{1B}{s_t} + 
T_s \cdot \eqmath{1C}{\dot{\underline{s}}_t}
\\
\eqmath{1A}{
  \begin{pmatrix}
  \theta_{t+1} \\ 
  \dot{\theta}_{t+1} \\ 
  x_{t+1} \\ 
  \dot{x}_{t+1}
  \end{pmatrix}
} &=
\eqmath{1B}{
  \begin{pmatrix}
  \theta_t \\ 
  \dot{\theta}_t \\ 
  x_t \\ 
  \dot{x}_t   
  \end{pmatrix}
} + 
T_s \cdot \eqmath{1C}{
  \begin{pmatrix}
  \dot{\theta}_t \\ 
  \ddot{\theta}_t \\ 
  \dot{x}_t \\ 
  \ddot{x}_t  
  \end{pmatrix}
}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Now compare with

[image]

and decide that this is better, because it assumes the reader can read. The code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{eqparbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{gather}
\underline{s}_{t+1} = s_t + T_s \cdot \dot{\underline{s}}_t
\\
\begin{pmatrix}
  \theta_{t+1} \\ 
  \dot{\theta}_{t+1} \\ 
  x_{t+1} \\ 
  \dot{x}_{t+1}
\end{pmatrix} =
\begin{pmatrix}
  \theta_t \\ 
  \dot{\theta}_t \\ 
  x_t \\ 
  \dot{x}_t   
\end{pmatrix} +
T_s \cdot
\begin{pmatrix}
  \dot{\theta}_t \\ 
  \ddot{\theta}_t \\ 
  \dot{x}_t \\ 
  \ddot{x}_t  
\end{pmatrix}
\end{gather}

\end{document}
```

Even better, add some explanatory text:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\underline{s}_{t+1} = s_t + T_s \cdot \dot{\underline{s}}_t
\end{equation}
which becomes, in our particular case,
\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}
  \theta_{t+1} \\ 
  \dot{\theta}_{t+1} \\ 
  x_{t+1} \\ 
  \dot{x}_{t+1}
\end{pmatrix} =
\begin{pmatrix}
  \theta_t \\ 
  \dot{\theta}_t \\ 
  x_t \\ 
  \dot{x}_t   
\end{pmatrix} +
T_s \cdot
\begin{pmatrix}
  \dot{\theta}_t \\ 
  \ddot{\theta}_t \\ 
  \dot{x}_t \\ 
  \ddot{x}_t  
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I guess the third version would have made it much easier. Thanks for the detailed answer ^^

Answer (score 3):

Here is an easy way based on the standard `array` environment. You can choose the separation between columns using `\arraycolsep` length.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}


\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  \setlength{\arraycolsep}{.3em}
  \begin{array}{ccccccc}
    \underline{s}_{t+1}
    &=& s_t &+& T_s &\cdot& \dot{\underline{s}_t}\\[1ex]
    \begin{pmatrix}
      \theta_{t+1}\\ 
      \dot{\theta}_{t+1}\\ 
      x_{t+1}\\ 
      \dot{x}_{t+1}
    \end{pmatrix}
    &=&
        \begin{pmatrix}
          \theta_t \\ 
          \dot{\theta}_t \\ 
          x_t \\ 
          \dot{x}_t   
        \end{pmatrix}
    &+& T_s  &\cdot&
        \begin{pmatrix}
          \dot{\theta}_t \\ 
          \ddot{\theta}_t \\ 
          \dot{x}_t \\ 
          \ddot{x}_t  
        \end{pmatrix}
  \end{array}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you only need one equation number, you could stack the top equation over the elements of the bottom equation.  Here, I use a `L`ongstack to get a fixed baselineskip between the equations, which I set at `38pt`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,stackengine}
\stackMath
\begin{document}
\renewcommand\stacktype{L}
\setstackgap{L}{38pt}
\begin{align}
  \stackon{\begin{pmatrix}
    \theta_{t+1} \\ 
    \dot{\theta}_{t+1} \\ 
    x_{t+1} \\ 
    \dot{x}_{t+1}
  \end{pmatrix}}{\underline{s}_{t+1}}
    &\stackon{{}={}}{=}
  \stackon{\begin{pmatrix}
    \theta_t \\ 
    \dot{\theta}_t \\ 
    x_t \\ 
    \dot{x}_t   
    \end{pmatrix}}{s_t}
     \stackon{{}+ T_s \cdot{}}{{}+ T_s \cdot{}}
  \stackon{\begin{pmatrix}
    \dot{\theta}_t \\ 
    \ddot{\theta}_t \\ 
    \dot{x}_t \\ 
    \ddot{x}_t  
  \end{pmatrix}}{\dot{\underline{s}_t}}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]